# Next.js TypeScript Build Error: Type 'OmitWithTag<InputFormProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types, build

`So i have a project in Next Js and i use TypeScript. I tried to build my project using npm run build and after terminals says this:

```
# Type 'OmitWithTag<InputFormProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
# Property 'type' is incompatible with index signature.
# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
# 
# 26 |
# 27 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
# 28 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
#      |             ^
# 29 |
# 30 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
# 31 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {
```

I found a file where my error appeared and it is located in .next folder which i didnt change or touched, it was created automatically during building. here is the code for it:

```
     // File: C:\Users\igovt\OneDrive\Desktop\MeetUps\meet-ups\meetups\app\components\InputForm\page.tsx
import * as entry from '../../../../../app/components/InputForm/page.js'
import type { ResolvingMetadata, ResolvingViewport } from 'next/dist/lib/metadata/types/metadata-interface.js'

type TEntry = typeof import('../../../../../app/components/InputForm/page.js')

// Check that the entry is a valid entry
checkFields<Diff<{
  default: Function
  config?: {}
  generateStaticParams?: Function
  revalidate?: RevalidateRange<TEntry> | false
  dynamic?: 'auto' | 'force-dynamic' | 'error' | 'force-static'
  dynamicParams?: boolean
  fetchCache?: 'auto' | 'force-no-store' | 'only-no-store' | 'default-no-store' | 'default-cache' | 'only-cache' | 'force-cache'
  preferredRegion?: 'auto' | 'global' | 'home' | string | string[]
  runtime?: 'nodejs' | 'experimental-edge' | 'edge'
  maxDuration?: number
  
  metadata?: any
  generateMetadata?: Function
  viewport?: any
  generateViewport?: Function
  
}, TEntry, ''>>()

// Check the prop type of the entry function
checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()

// Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {
  checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
  checkFields<Diff<ResolvingMetadata, SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
}

// Check the arguments and return type of the generateViewport function
if ('generateViewport' in entry) {
  checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateViewport'>>, 'generateViewport'>>()
  checkFields<Diff<ResolvingViewport, SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateViewport'>>, 'generateViewport'>>()
}

// Check the arguments and return type of the generateStaticParams function
if ('generateStaticParams' in entry) {
  checkFields<Diff<{ params: PageParams }, FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateStaticParams'>>, 'generateStaticParams'>>()
  checkFields<Diff<{ __tag__: 'generateStaticParams', __return_type__: any[] | Promise<any[]> }, { __tag__: 'generateStaticParams', __return_type__: ReturnType<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateStaticParams'>> }>>()
}

type PageParams = any
export interface PageProps {
  params?: any
  searchParams?: any
}
export interface LayoutProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode

  params?: any
}

// =============
// Utility types
type RevalidateRange<T> = T extends { revalidate: any } ? NonNegative<T['revalidate']> : never

// If T is unknown or any, it will be an empty {} type. Otherwise, it will be the same as Omit<T, keyof Base>.
type OmitWithTag<T, K extends keyof any, _M> = Omit<T, K>
type Diff<Base, T extends Base, Message extends string = ''> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? {} : OmitWithTag<T, keyof Base, Message>

type FirstArg<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: [infer T, any]) => any ? unknown extends T ? any : T : never
type SecondArg<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: [any, infer T]) => any ? unknown extends T ? any : T : never
type MaybeField<T, K extends string> = T extends { [k in K]: infer G } ? G extends Function ? G : never : never



function checkFields<_ extends { [k in keyof any]: never }>() {}

// https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest
type Numeric = number | bigint
type Zero = 0 | 0n
type Negative<T extends Numeric> = T extends Zero ? never : `${T}` extends `-${string}` ? T : never
type NonNegative<T extends Numeric> = T extends Zero ? T : Negative<T> extends never ? T : '__invalid_negative_number__'
```

Error is in line:  **// Check the prop type of the entry function
checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()**

I dont know what i was doing wrong and i dont know how to fix it. I checked how i use my props and it is OK. You can check the code below for my InputForm.tsx component and you will see how i set props(i have a separete file with interfaces):

```
      'use client'
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from './inputform.module.scss';
import { InputFormProps } from "../../actions/Interface";


const InputForm: React.FC<InputFormProps> = ({ type, placeholder }) => {
  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState(type);

  const toggleInputVisibility = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the modal from closing
    setInputType(currentType => (currentType === "password" ? "text" : "password"));
  };

  return (


    <div className={styles.inputForm}>
      <input
        type={inputType}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className={styles.inputBlock} />


      {type === "password" && (
        <button
          onClick={toggleInputVisibility}
          className={styles.hidePasswordIcon}
          aria-label={inputType === "password" ? 'Show password' : 'Hide password'}
        >
          {inputType === "password" ? (

            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M1 12C1 12 5 4 12 4C19 4 23 12 23 12C23 12 19 20 12 20C5 20 1 12 1 12Z" stroke="#505050" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
              <path d="M12 15C13.6569 15 15 13.6569 15 12C15 10.3431 13.6569 9 12 9C10.3431 9 9 10.3431 9 12C9 13.6569 10.3431 15 12 15Z" stroke="#505050" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
            </svg>
          ) : (

            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <g clipPath="url(#clip0_150_2589)">
                <path d="M17.94 17.94C16.2306 19.243 14.1491 19.9649 12 20C5 20 1 12 1 12C2.24389 9.68192 3.96914 7.65663 6.06 6.06003M9.9 4.24002C10.5883 4.0789 11.2931 3.99836 12 4.00003C19 4.00003 23 12 23 12C22.393 13.1356 21.6691 14.2048 20.84 15.19M14.12 14.12C13.8454 14.4148 13.5141 14.6512 13.1462 14.8151C12.7782 14.9791 12.3809 15.0673 11.9781 15.0744C11.5753 15.0815 11.1752 15.0074 10.8016 14.8565C10.4281 14.7056 10.0887 14.4811 9.80385 14.1962C9.51897 13.9113 9.29439 13.572 9.14351 13.1984C8.99262 12.8249 8.91853 12.4247 8.92563 12.0219C8.93274 11.6191 9.02091 11.2219 9.18488 10.8539C9.34884 10.4859 9.58525 10.1547 9.88 9.88003" stroke="#505050" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
                <path d="M1 1L23 23" stroke="#505050" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
              </g>
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_150_2589">
                  <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
          )}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputForm;
```

Please, help. I already spent a lot of time on it, deadline is soon

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using async/await syntax with an arrow function page component. If you are, you can try converting it to named function. That is what I did to fix a similar issue in my project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).